# Unable to bind $scope objects in ng-model for input

Tags: angularjs, json, dom, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to bind my Controller's object values to inputs using ng-model, if I add it ng-repeat it is binding data, but if i call it directly it is not binding data to inputs. Thank you :)

**Angular Controller**

```
SMSApp.controller('studentUpdateController', function ($scope, $routeParams, GetStudentService) {
    $scope.stuid = $routeParams.STUDENTID != null ? $routeParams.STUDENTID : 0;
    GetStudentService.getbyId($scope.stuid).then(function (result) {
        $scope.obj = JSON.parse(result);
        $scope.obj = $scope.obj.Table;
        console.log($scope.obj);
    });
});
```

**Console Log's**

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.FIRSTNAME" placeholder="First Name" required />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label>Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.MIDDLENAME" value="" placeholder="Middle Name" required />
</div>
```

Comment: Console output shows its an array. Change `$scope.obj.Table` to `$scope.obj.Table[0]`.

Comment: Always welcome friend.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your obj is an array. If you do not want to use ng-repeat in other words if you are sure you will have only 1 item in your array you can try the following

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj[0].FIRSTNAME" placeholder="First Name" required />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label>Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj[0].MIDDLENAME" value="" placeholder="Middle Name" required />
</div>
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.